# Is there a way to borrow hard drive memory as needed?

Tags: python, memory, computer-science

This might be a stupid question but if, for example, i'm working with very large arrays that take up 2.1 GB of RAM on my 2GB computer, is there a way to *borrow* the extra 0.1GB from my hard drive as needed?

Comment: What operating system? In Linux-like systems, this is purpose of swap space.

Comment: This is an operating system-level issue and most operating systems have a way of doing this automatically.

Comment: It's not a stupid question; it's an *excellent* idea. Which is why our forefathers implemented it in operating systems back in the 1960s! Have a read about [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) and [paging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging).

Answer (score 2):

Your operating system already does that (Windows, *nix). It's called [Virtual Memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory).

Comment: Virtual memory is a broader concept makes many other things possible as well (working around physical memory fragmentation, memory mapping files, etc). The particular process of borrowing HDD space is called swapping.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is part of [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), specifically swapping. Most modern operating systems do this without the programmer having to worry about it.

When physical RAM becomes exhausted, the harddisk is used as extra memory. This is *very* slow, because the access times for a harddisk (milliseconds) is in the order of a million times slower than that of DRAM (nanoseconds).

It would be advisable to increase your RAM, if possible.

Comment: Note that even with swap it's possible to run into virtual memory space issues, for instance on popular 32-bit operating systems you just can't access more than 4GB (or less) worth of virtual memory space (whether it maps to RAM or not), without some serious trickery.

Comment: As an added bonus, you actually have less than those 4 GiB of address space available. It's particular bad on Windows, where by default you only get 2 GB of virtual addresses (the rest is reserved for the system). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb613473%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: It depends a bit on the usage pattern whether it's slow. If you need random access to a dataset that's significantly larger than RAM, then you'll mostly be operating at the speed of disk, which is terrible. If the dataset is only slightly bigger than RAM, then most accesses will be hitting data that's still in RAM, so the slowdown will be much less.

Comment: @delnan: That's only true on 32-bit Windows; 64-bit applications running on 64-bit Windows do not have a 2GB limit.

Comment: @KenWhite Yes, should have mentioned. 32 bit binaries running on 64 bit windows also get 4GB address space, if massaged by an obscure tool.

Comment: @delnan: No obscure tool necessary. It's a simple PE flag, which many modern compiler/linkers will set for you. (Delphi and C++Builder, for instance, allow it to be set with a simple compiler define in the source code.)

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated yes the systems already have virtual memory.

**However you can take advantage of this in another way. You can use [memory mapped files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file) to allow the system to directly map the arrays to disk.**

Using it this way as you write to memory (the arrays), the system will use it's virtual memory management system to use the disk. You might ask how this is different to to standard VMM that the OS will do? Well the advantage is that it won't use the standard swap space (page file in windows) and as such that space is 'memory' is availble for the the rest of the system to use.

You still have large resource usage, but you gain by freeing up swap space and in effect, borrow more virtual memory. The other advantages you get is that there is no duplication of data. ie. if you're loading large datasets then you just map the disk space to memory and vice versa for writes.